# JPA - Filter MySQL DOUBLE (6,2) with LIKE of CriteriaQuery

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, criteria-api

i want to filter a DOUBLE (6,2) value from my database with the LIKE-Function of CriteriaQuery. But it throws a Exception:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: No authorized routine named 'LIKE' of type 'FUNCTION' having compatible arguments was found.
```

the code:

```
    stundensatz.ifPresent(s -> criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.like(mitarbeiter.get("stundensatz"), "%" + s + "%")));
```

"Stundensatz" means hourly rate. I did the same with a INTEGER, this worked fine. How can i filter a DOUBLE with LIKE? I really need help. I can't find a any articles about this here. I tried to convert the `mitarbeiter.get("stundensatz")` to a String or Integer, but this didnt work.

Thank you in advance.
sven_meye

Comment: how did you try to cast the doulbe to String?

Comment: since `like` works with a String only, then a cast is essential

Comment: I tried toString() and CriteriaBuilder.toString

Comment: but not TREAT ?

Comment: What is TREAT ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to use the `like` function with Numbers like this:

```
Expression plzInt = kategorie.get("nummer");
Expression plzStr = criteriaBuilder.function("CHAR", String.class, plzInt);
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.upper(plzStr), "%" + nummer.trim().toUpperCase() + "%"));
```